# Javascript inline if statement inside HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

How can I add `if` condition within the code so that I can  Enable/disable the value based on boolean?

I have defined boolean variable `isEnable`. Based on the value of isEnable, I want to enable/disable dropdown value `<option value="Close"> Close Amount</option>`.

Something like - `if(isEnable) then enable or disable Close Amount dropdown value`

Account.js

```
initGrid : function() {
            var self=this;
            this.isEnable= false;
            this._onlineIDDetailsGrid = this.findControl("#onlineIDDetailsGrid").DataTable({
                "columnDefs":[{className: "dt-body-center", "targets": [ 0,3,4,5]}],
                "columns": [
                        {
                            "title" : "Actions",
                            "render": function (data, type, full) {         
                                if ((self._access == CBTFLASH.UTILS.Constants.FULLCONTROL_ACCESS))              
                      
                                    return '<select class="ddlSelectAction dropdown_md" disabled="disabled" data-status="'+full.onlineIdStatus+'" data-value="'+full.onlineId+'" data-pwdstatus="'+full.passwordRevokeStatusCode+'" data-custguid="'+full.customerGuid+'">
<option value="">Select Action</option>
<option value="SUSPEND">Suspend</option>
<option value="UNSUSPEND">Unsuspend</option>
<option value="REVOKE">Revoke</option>
<option value="Close">Close Amount</option>--------------------> This dropdown option
<option value="ZELLETOKEN">Block/Unblock Zelle Token</option></select>';
                            }   
                        },
}
```

Comment: you can use ternary conditional ( `isEnable ? "user is enabled" : "access denied" `) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas, Where should I add this? Do I need to add delimiters to separate `<option value="Close">Close Amount</option>` with above code? As I have to enable/disable just 1 dropdown value

Comment: I guess this question came from someone in the same class as you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72885802/519413. Your answer is the same.