# How to add inline Javascript if condition to dropdown value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu, boolean

How can I add an `if` condition within the code so that I can  enable/disable the select based on boolean flag?

I have defined boolean property named `isEnable`. Based on this value  I want to enable/disable the dropdown value `<option value="Close"> Close Amount</option>`.

Something like - `if(isEnable) then enable or disable Close Amount dropdown value`

```js
initGrid: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.isEnable = false;
  this._onlineIDDetailsGrid = this.findControl("#onlineIDDetailsGrid").DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      className: "dt-body-center",
      "targets": [0, 3, 4, 5]
    }],
    "columns": [{
      "title": "Actions",
      "render": function(data, type, full) {
        return '<select class="ddlSelectAction dropdown_md" disabled="disabled"> <
          option value = "" > Select Action < /option> <
          option value = "SUSPEND" > Suspend < /option> <
          option value = "Close" > Close Amount < /option>;--------------------> This dropdown option
      }
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you can use a ternary expression to concatenate the `disabled` attribute to the `select` HTML if `isEnable` is false. This can be made simpler still by using a template literal:

```js
"columns": [{
    "title": "Actions",
    "render": function(data, type, full) {
      return `<select class="ddlSelectAction dropdown_md">
        <option value="">Select Action</option>
        <option value="SUSPEND">Suspend</option> 
        <option value="Close" ${(self.isEnable ? '' : 'disabled="disabled"')}>Close Amount</option>
      </select>`
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, it give error at `'disabled="disabled"` - Semi colon expected

Comment: Works ok in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/b5seyw3a/. Are you sure you included the code correctly, and also which browser are you testing with?

Comment: Chrome, ok let me check, using Eclipse IDE

Comment: I replaced with with `{(this._isEnable ?) "": disabled="disabled")}`. Error is gone but button is not disabling :( Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: Yes, you have mismatched parentheses. Literally just copy+paste what I wrote in to your code.

Comment: My bad, I typed it wrong here. This is what I have `${(this._isEnable ? "": disabled="disabled")}`

Comment: If I add `' '` around  `disabled="disabled"`. Gives error so I removed them